# Laravel 7.x migration changing columns question

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I made users table.

but I want chage some column attribute.
example)
before column

```
 enum('role', ['S', 'T', 'A'])->comment('account type (S=student, T=teacher, A=admin)')
```

but I want change like this,

```
 enum('role', ['S', 'T', 'A', 'P'])->commen('account type (S=student, T=teacher, A=admin, P=parent)->change();
```

so I make migration file

modify_column_to_users_table.php

```
public function up()
{
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->enum('role', ['S', 'T', 'A', 'P'])->commen('account type (S=student, T=teacher, A=admin, P=parent)->change();
});
}
```

and I did...  `php artisan migrate`
but It's error.

Please help me, how to fix it?

Comment: P=parent)')->change(); missing quotation ~ not this problems~

Comment: If you have made a copy paste from your migration file, there are two easy spot on problems: ``commen`` in lieu of ``comment()``, and you didn't close the quotation mark of the second part, it should be ``->comment('account type (S=student, T=teacher, A=admin, P=parent)')``

Comment: yes~ It is typing mistake but Not this one.

Comment: Oh~ That's right~. Thank you so much~. It is working~.
God bless you~